# How to submit a job to a specific node using Slurm's sbatch command?

Tags: command-line, cluster, slurm

Our nodes are named `node001` ... `node0xx` in our cluster. I wonder, is it possible to submit a job to a specific node using Slurm's `sbatch` command? If so, can someone post an example code for that?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to use `-w node0xx` or `--nodelist=node0xx`.

Comment: You need to provide the partition too lest you want to get a "requested node not in this partition" error as some nodes can be in several partitions (in my case we have a node that's in the fat and the fat_short partitions).

Comment: [Here is the link](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_nodelistand) to the documentation for `sbatch` on the `-w` flag.